# Change color highlight of icons in QTableView, when the cell is selected

Tags: c++, user-interface, qtableview

When a cell is selected in QTableView, the icons in it are given a blue highlight, how can I control the color of this highlight or disable it?

I tried setting the QPalette::Highlight but it didn't work.

Edit:

Okay, so I do know how to change the background color and text color and color highlight, but not for an icon. If I return an icon as decoration for a cell, it is given a light blue highlight when the cell is selected. How do I remove this?

Comment: Is the icon's background transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's utterly impossible to change this behavior with the standard style in Qt. You need to implement your own specific style in order to work around this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use style sheets to define the color of your elements. The name of the selected item in your `QTableView` is `selection-background-color`. So, changing the color of this element you will chose the background color that your prefer.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTableView *table = new QTableView();
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(2,2);

    table->setModel(model);
    table->setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: red");

    table->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Look how it looks in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't do anything to the icon. At least I didn't get it to do. Can you make it do that?

Comment: When you say "icon" you mean the "table header"?

Comment: No, an icon you can set by returning an image as a decoration item for a cell. Each cell can have it's own icon.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a way around this issue, but it has some cost associated with it.

Fundamentally, deep within Qt code it is calling onto `QIcon::paint()` and passing `QIcon::Selected` as the icon mode, so the issue is that the "selected" form of the icon's pixmap at the desired resolution is the one auto-generated by Qt.

I worked around this by setting the `Selected` form of the icon to be the same as the `Normal` mode:

```
  // Make the "Selected" version of the icon look the same as "Normal".
  for (const auto& size : icon.availableSizes())
  {
    icon.addPixmap(icon.pixmap(size, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off),
                   QIcon::Selected, QIcon::Off);
    icon.addPixmap(icon.pixmap(size, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On),
                   QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);
  }
```

[image: sampleWithNonSelectedIconInTable]

The downside is extra time spent doing this, possibly extra memory to store it, and wasted time generating the selected icons that we're throwing away.

In my case I'm using a `QStyledItemDelegate` and unfortunately that doesn't give you the ability to more closely influencing how the icon is rendered without completely reimplementing how `QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem` is rendered in your style.

Come to think of it, if you use a proxy style it wouldn't be too hard to override how `CE_ItemViewItem` is rendered to not use a selected icon, so that would be an option too.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Here's the solution I ended up using:
`QIcon icon(file_path)`
`icon.addFile(file_path, QSize(), QIcon::Selected)`